# Why some drives have FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM attributes?

Tags: windows, pywin32, drive

I am working on windows recently, and I need to get file's attributes, therefore I referenced Microsoft document [File Attribute Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants).

However, I encountered a problem and I couldn't find any explanation on the document.

Here is my question ():

I used `win32file.GetFileAttributes("D:\\")` and got flag number `22`, which means `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY (16)` + `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN (2)` + `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM (4)`.

*I am wondering why Drive D has attribute `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN (2)`.* ??

Drive C, F, E, H has same situation. Drive U is USB, its flag number is `16`

Below is my all drives

```
DISKPART> list volume
Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     F   New Volume   NTFS   Simple        29 GB  Healthy
Volume 1     E   New Volume   NTFS   Simple        48 GB  Healthy
Volume 2         New Volume   NTFS   Simple        48 GB  Healthy
C:\mount_v1\
Volume 3     H   aaaaaa       NTFS   Simple        48 GB  Healthy
Volume 4     D   New Volume   NTFS   Simple        48 GB  Healthy
Volume 5     C   Windows 10   NTFS   Partition     39 GB  Healthy    System   
Volume 6     U   USBDisk1     FAT32  Removable   7391 MB  Healthy
```

Comment: Why are you referring to the root directory as the drive itself? Anyway, this is an NTFS thing. The root directory is file number 5. The first 16 files are reserved by the filesystem for internal or special use, such as "$Mft" (0) and "$Extend" (11). These files have the hidden and system attributes permanently enabled and most are inaccessible. If you try to set the root directory attributes to just `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` (16) via `SetFileAttributes`, it succeeds but the directory will still have the hidden and system attributes set.

Comment: @ErykSun Thanks for your reply. I just want to filter some files belong to hidden folder. For example, suppose "hf_a" is a hidden folder, then I will ignore it and its content. Unfortunately, some files live in root folder D, such as D:\abc.jpg, I will check the attributes of file's parent, means root folder D, and D is regarded as the hidden folder since D has `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`. That's the reason why I tried `win32file.GetFileAttributes("D:\\")` to check attributes.

Comment: If the root directory is hidden, you can either keep it in the general case or except it as a special case. It really is a special case because the root directory has no parent. Even if it's mounted at another path, the mountpoint (a type of filesystem reparse point) will have its own unrelated file attributes, and `GetFileAttributes` opens a reparse point directly instead of letting the system reparse to the target.